# How to deploy Nuxt ssr to Cpanel

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm new to vueJs and nuxt and i'm trying to deploy my nuxt app to my server, I tried the command `npm run build` and I have two files, client and server, I googled what should I do with this files but I got Nothing, So how to deploy my app to cpanel?

Comment: Haha, 601 days later: my answer is finally accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target is `server` (default), you indeed need to do `npm run build`. Then, you have a generated `dist` that you need to send to the server and then `npm run start`.

Sometimes, additional configuration is required and can be found in the deployment pages. There is no `Cpanel` but you maybe can find something that looks like the same here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deploying-to-21yunbox